# TextChanged event does not fire when type the same text

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

i am working on ajax autoextender, there is one dropdownlist and textbox everything is works fine but while i am going to type in text box 'X' it produce the result but while i am change the dropdown selected index and type the same text 'X' in text box the text changed event not firing, any one know the reason please let me know,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The TextChanged event only fire when the text in control is changed and focus go out the control. You can set text of control is empty when got focus to control to fire TextChanged event.

Comment: i did that ie i empty the textbox while i changed the selected index in dropdown through javascript.